# Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse info about running app

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tools-4

I am new to Spring and trying to understand a few things. In spring docs read about spring tools and thought to give it a try.

I installed Spring Tools 4.9.0 from Eclipse Marketplace and use it to import a tutorial project (File > New > Other > Import Spring Getting Started Context). Run the app with Boot Dashboard and it works as it should.

Saw in some tutorial videos when the app runs annotations become greenish and if you hover over them you get info like bean id etc.
In my case nothing like that happens. Do i need to configure something in eclipse or am i missing something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you are running the application, go to spring application class and are you finding @SpringBootApplication, hover on it

Comment: @GvSharma i see javadoc info as before spring tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are referring to is the "Live Application Information", the user guide section for this is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Live-Application-Information.

In order to have an app showing that live information in the tools, it has to have the spring boot actuators on the classpath: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html.

Depending on the exact guide that you chose it might not have actuators on the classpath out-of-the-box. In that case, add the actuator dependency to your pom.xml file, do a "Maven -> Update Project" from the context menu and start the app again using the dashboard. Then the green live information highlights should appear.

Comment: Tried a few things. In the end i imported Actuator Service from tutorials([spring.io/guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/)) still not working

Comment: Once you started the app from the boot dashboard, is there anything showing up in the dropdown when you click on the lightbulb icon? Might be worth filing an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues, so that we can investigate this in more detail. What operating system are you running on?

Comment: Found out my eclipse's version was 4.16.0. I updated to 4.18.0 and it worked. My bad, i should had checked that first. Thank you.